# Android ExoPlayer Playback speed very fast on Android 4.2 version

Tags: android, performance, audio, playback, exoplayer

It looks like on Android 4.2 (Jelly bean) has an issue using ExoPlayer Library. When used for Audio purpose to stream live music, the Playback is played at double the speed.

I have raised an issue at the Github for ExoPlayer but no positive reply till yet.

Anyone with any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this symptom will happen when any given player (not specific to Exo) cannot resolve from the source media either/or the input's sample-rate or bit-depth - If you start with one song using known values, say sample-rate 44100 Hertz and a bit-depth of 16 bits which are typical audio defaults, play this then convert it into permutations, say bit-depth of 8 bits to see if this makes a difference

Comment: In my case I know about the bit rate (16 KBPS). But really don't know where to set the bit-rate in case of ExoPlayer. And only 4.2 devices that have this issue. I tried emulating 4.2 and it works fine there. Any idea on where to set the bit rate in case of ExoPlayer?

Comment: I'm going to implement ExoPlayer for streaming audio.  We use AAC format wrapped in an m3u8 file.  Should I expect this problem?  My understanding was that the AAC encoding will determine the correct playback speed.